# fabric CA client user enrolment authorisation failure

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am trying to enroll admin after initialising fabric CA server with:

```
 fabric-ca-server init -b “admin:adminpw”
```

And starting CA server with:

```
fabric-ca-server start -b “admin:adminpw”
```

At client-side, enroll command:

```
fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://admin:adminpw@localhost:7054
```

Client-side error message:

```
[INFO] generating key: &{A:ecdsa S:256}
[INFO] encoded CSR
Error: Response from server: Error Code: 20 - Authorization failure
```

Server-side:

```
fabric-ca-server start -b “admin:adminpw”
2018/08/27 14:48:57 [INFO] Configuration file location: 
/home/nadeem/Documents/Fabric-CA/server/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml
2018/08/27 14:48:57 [INFO] Starting server in home directory: 
/home/nadeem/Documents/Fabric-CA/server
2018/08/27 14:48:57 [INFO] Server Version: 1.2.1-snapshot-3bcdbb2
2018/08/27 14:48:57 [INFO] Server Levels: &{Identity:1 Affiliation:1 
Certificate:1 Credential:1 RAInfo:1 Nonce:1}
2018/08/27 14:48:57 [INFO] The CA key and certificate already exist
2018/08/27 14:48:57 [INFO] The key is stored by BCCSP provider 'SW'
2018/08/27 14:48:57 [INFO] The certificate is at: 
/home/nadeem/Documents/Fabric-CA/server/ca-cert.pem
2018/08/27 14:48:57 [INFO] Initialized sqlite3 database at 
/home/nadeem/Documents/Fabric-CA/server/fabric-ca-server.db
2018/08/27 14:48:57 [INFO] Home directory for default CA: 
/home/nadeem/Documents/Fabric-CA/server
2018/08/27 14:48:57 [INFO] Listening on http://0.0.0.0:7054
***2018/08/27 14:49:34 [INFO] 127.0.0.1:46350 POST /enroll 401 23 "Failed 
to get user: : scode: 404, code: 63, msg: Failed to get User: sql: no 
rows in result set"***
```

fabric-ca-client/server:

> Version: 1.2.1-snapshot-3bcdbb2  Go version: go1.11  OS/Arch:
>   linux/amd64

Found similar post here:

> https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FABC-302

It is marked resolved with v1.2 but there are no clear instructions on how to resolve it now.
Thanks :)

Comment: I am also facing the same issues,the difference is that I am doing everything on AWS using AWS Blockchain Managed Service.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to make Fabric-CA work for a while,
The best advice I can give you is to take off the "" around the admin credentials before you start. I do not put them and it works for me.
So commands would be :

```
fabric-ca-server init -b admin:adminpw

fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that and didn't work. I am advised to use fabric-ca version-1.2.0-stable rather that 1.2.1. I'll do that and update this comment. This bug was present in v1.1 and considered resolved in v1.2.0 and seems to be present in v1.2.1

Comment: I was able to setup CA with v1.2.0 June 18 release.

Answer (score 0):

this error message appear. Account and password are not same when ca start and when you use ca enroll use.

Answer (score 0):

#### Error Code: 20 - Authorization failure

Error code 20 arises due to the following condition.
Suppose you have registered the identity like this :-

```
fabric-ca-client  register --id.name org1 --id.type client --id.affiliation org1 --id.attrs '"hf.Registrar.Roles=user,client,peer","hf.AffiliationMgr=true","hf.Revoker=true"'
```

which is giving you the output

```
2020/02/05 11:19:25 [INFO] Configuration file location: /home/username/myPros/caclient/admin/fabric-ca-client-config.yaml
Password: ZXCbhJajCObX
```

and you are trying to enroll the user/identity like this :-

```
fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://org1-admin:ZXCbhJajCObX@localhost:7054
```

**or**

```
fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://org1-admin:adminpw@localhost:7054
```

so long story short either your enrollment Id or your password is mismatched. Make sure that your username and password are not mismatched.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly during init. Look in your fabric-ca-server-config.yaml file for these quotation marks and remove them. Do not use them during init enroll.

[image: image of fabric-ca-server-config.yaml file]

Comment: Thank you @tomerpacific -  my low rep didnt allow me to use the image - only the link.